# Vue-cli3 demo use vue-router routing to pages not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to learn vue-router and I have a problem with vue-cli3 + vue-router demo.

This demo use `vue create` default create.
I've tried to minimize the demo, but it is still not work.

this is `main.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.use(VueRouter)

const Foo = { template: '<div>foo</div>' }

const routes = [
  { path: '/foo', component: Foo }
]

new Vue({
  router: new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: routes
  }),
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

this is `App.vue`

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
    <!--HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App"/-->
    <router-link to="/foo">Go to Foo</router-link>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'

export default {
  // name: 'app'
  // components: {
  //   HelloWorld
  // }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

vue and vue-router version

```
"vue": "^2.6.10",
"vue-router": "^3.1.3"
```

I don't know why it doesn't work. Can you help me?

Comment: Are any errors thrown in the console or browser? You might have missing dependencies? The code above should be working.

Comment: @MarcRo Christian Carrillo's answer is right, but thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

`import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js'`

instead of

`import Vue from 'vue'`

[here](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/215) have a topic about this and vue template.